# unable to delete security groups from amazon aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have created the three security groups for the testing purpose on `amazon aws`. Now I want to delete them. But, every time I try to delete them it gives me the error:
Group XXXXXXX:`testcluster` is used by groups: XXXXXXXX:`testcluster-master` XXXXXXX:`testcluster-zookeeper`

Also, there is no option to delete multiple groups. How can I delete them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules will reappear in the security group if you do not save any changes done.
You will have to do the following:

1. Go to your security group "testcluster-zookeeper".
2. Delete all referenced rules to testcluster
3. Press the "apply rule changes" button
4. Go to testcluster-master repeat steps 2 and 3

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by editing the groups I wanted to remove and then deleting each and every inbound and outbound rule.  Once this change was made I was able to delete the groups that were referencing each other.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to delete also reference in ElastiCache security groups.

Answer (score 1):

First delete all dependencies between the groups (any rules that refer one to the other) and then you can delete the groups themselves.

Comment: I tried earlier before your reply what you suggested. But, the problem is that if lets say I delete the "testcluster" inbound rule first from "testcluster-zookeeper" and then move to "testcluster-master". By the time I move to "testcluster-master" those inbound rules again comes in the "testcluster-zookeeper". So, I am not able to delete any of those groups.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not able to delete this is simple, Security Group you want to delete is being used in some other Security Groups Inbound/Outbound rules. Please delete them and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you encountered the same problem as mine.
I have 2 security groups refers to each other. I tried delete them many times but didn't work. Then I realized inbound rules of them refers to each others. I deleted the inbound rules first --> delete the groups --> works

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30191869)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite tricky to delete instances from AWS, especially EMR instances as for some reason they keep getting automatically recreated on deletion. The simplest way I found was to go to the VPC settings and delete those. Was very helpful there on to delete the rest of the stuff. 
P.S. I was trying to delete all my instances, hence took this route. In fact i decided to close my account which i had created for academic purposes. I did lose a lot of money unintentionally since i left the instances on for a couple of days, my bad! :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure you delete , in-bound references of chosen security group from other security groups , vice-versa. I encountered this issue , removed in-bound/outbound references to fix

Answer (score 0):

First, select VPC Feature, then go to Security Groups page and delete one by one

Where is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W681F.png